# How to retrieve all data in one column from mysql JDBC android studio

Tags: android, mysql

I want to retrieve these data

[image]

And display in textview like this:

[image]

I am using android studio and mysql JDBC. I hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance.

Here are my codes:

```
try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            if (conn == null) {
                success = false;
            }
            else {

                String query = "SELECT pin FROM request";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if (rs != null) 
                {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        try {

                            String val = rs.getString(1);
                            list.add(val);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    int arraySize = list.size();
                    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        textView.append(list.get(i));
                    }


                    success = true;
                } else {

                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: SO is not a write code for me community. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: i don't know how to retrieve it just like how the second picture shows. i need codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems even you don't need to itirate the "rs" if you just wanted to stored in textView:

```
String query = "SELECT group_concat(pin) FROM request";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
String textView = rs.getString(1);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!